# Check part of my proof (dense completion of a metric space)

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

Part of the proof that every metric space has a dense completion is to 
show that the metric $\tilde{d}([(x_n)], [(y_n)]) = \lim_n d(x_n, y_n)$, 
where $d$ is the original metric (in the possibly incomplete metric space) and $(x_n), (y_n)$ are Cauchy, is independent of choice of representative. I've written my proof up below.

(Note that the equivalence relation I'm using is the standard one: $(z_n) \sim (z'_n)$ (Cauchy sequences) if $\lim_n d(z_n, z'_n) = 0$.)

**Proof**:

To show it is well defined, 
we must show that it 
is independent of choice of 
representative. Indeed, 
suppose that $(x_n) \sim 
(x'_n)$ and $(y_n) \sim 
(y'_n)$. We must show that 
$\lim_{n \to \infty} 
d(x_n, y_n) = \lim_{n \to \infty} 
d(x'_n, y'_n)$. From the triangle inequality: 
\begin{align*}
d(x_n, y_n) &\leq 
d(x'_n, y'_n) + d(y'_n, y_n) + 
d(x_n, x'_n)\\
d(x'_n, y'_n) &\leq 
d(x_n, y_n) + d(y'_n, y_n) + 
d(x_n, x'_n).
\end{align*}
Thus, rearranging the inequalities 
above gives 
$|d(x_n, y_n) - d(x'_n, y'_n)|
\leq d(y'_n, y_n) + 
d(x_n, x'_n)$.
Passing to the limit superior:
$$
\limsup_{n \to \infty} |d(x_n, y_n) - d(x'_n, y'_n)| \leq 
\lim_n d(y'_n, y_n) + \lim_n
d(x_n, x'_n) = 0. 
$$
But this implies that 
$\lim_n d(x_n, y_n) = 
\lim_n d(x'_n, y'_n)$, as desired.

**Question (1):** Is my proof correct?

**Question (2):** How do we know that $\lim_n d(x_n, y_n)$ exists? I'm silently relying on this fact in my proof.

Answer (score 1):

First establish the following:

If $(x_n)_n$ and $(y_n)_n$ are $d$-Cauchy, the limit of $d_n:=(d(x_n, y_n))_n$ exists because it is a Cauchy sequence in the reals.
Just as in your estimates we get $|d_n -d_m| = |d(x_n, y_n) - d(x_m, y_m)| \le d(x_n, x_m) + d(y_n, y_m)$. And then we use the definition of Cauchy sequence for $\frac{\varepsilon}{2}$ for $(x_n)_n$ and likewise for $(y_n)_n$ and we get that $(d_n)_n$ is Cauchy in the reals, and so convergent (we use that $(\mathbb{R} ,|\cdot|)$ is complete).

By your estimates the real-valued sequence $|d(x_n, y_n) - d(x'_n, y'_n)|$ is upper bounded by a sequence $c_n$ that tends to $0$. So it also tends to $0$, and this implies that the limits of the two sequences $(d(x_n, y_n))_n$ and $(d(x'_n, y'_n))_n$ (which *both* exist by the first part) are equal.